# Buildin template tags seem to break i18n

Tags: python, django, localization, django-templates, django-1.4

And just when I thought I am finished with the Internationalization and timezones and can finally move on to more interesting features, one last time I got bitten. :)

Within my template as long as I have the following, the template automatically converts the datetime from UTC into my currently selected timezone. And I can also switch to a different culture (US to UK format) and the date and time format does change accordingly. Simply perfect.

```
{% load l10n %}
{% for item in calls %}
     <td>{{ item.conversation_datetime }}</td>
     <td>{{ item.conversation_datetime }}</td>
{% endfor %}
```

Now all I need to do is to extract the localized date for the former and localized time for the latter. So I thought lets bang a template tag in there and life is good.

```
{% load l10n %}
{% for item in calls %}
     <td>{{ item.conversation_datetime|date }}</td>
     <td>{{ item.conversation_datetime|time }}</td>
{% endfor %}
```

But if life was good, I wouldn't be sitting here and writing this would I? ;)
The moment these filters are set, the format for these two fields seems to be fixed to the US culture. Date format is mm/dd/yyyy and time is 12 hrs am/pm.

Selecting the British language as I did before successfully has no longer any effect.

For the matter of fact I have overriden formats.py for `en` and `en-gb` and can confirm that en/format.py has the entry `TIME_FORMAT = 'P'` which corresponds to 12 hrs am/pm.

While the en_GB/formats.py has the `TIME_FORMAT = 'G:i'` which corresponds to 24 hrs.
Do you think there is another bit to using filter tags in templates that I have overlooked?

Comment: Which Django version are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit: the second approach is the solution. See also the comments below.

The behaviour that you observe is indeed mentioned in the documentation (see [date filter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/?from=olddocs#date)):

> When used without a format string: `{{ value|date }}` the formatting string defined in the `DATE_FORMAT` setting will be used, *without applying any localization*.

The same is mentioned for the `time` filter. From what I can see in the documentation, you can force localization with the `localize` filter:

```
{% load l10n %}
{% for item in calls %}
     <td>{{ item.conversation_datetime|date|localize }}</td>
     <td>{{ item.conversation_datetime|time|localize }}</td>
{% endfor %}
```

Alternatively, you can pass the setting that you wish to use (*the solution*):

```
{% load l10n %}
{% for item in calls %}
     <td>{{ item.conversation_datetime|date:"DATE_FORMAT" }}</td>
     <td>{{ item.conversation_datetime|time:"TIME_FORMAT" }}</td>
{% endfor %}
```

The documentation says regarding this:

> The format passed can be one of the predefined ones `DATE_FORMAT`, `DATETIME_FORMAT`, `SHORT_DATE_FORMAT` or `SHORT_DATETIME_FORMAT`, or a custom format that uses the format specifiers shown in the table above. *Note that predefined formats may vary depending on the current locale.*

Comment: I appreciate your help Simeon, I know these topics are shunned by most people. :)  I have tried both your solutions. The first one is exactly as before -> ignoring-culture-fixed-format. The second one is even better, nothing appears at all. Both date and time are empty. I will create a tiny sandbox app this afternoon to demonstrate the problem.  I also discovered Django 1.5 has a new tag called LocalTime.  It seems the Django-boys are aware of this shortcoming.  https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/utils/#django.utils.timezone.localtime  But they seem to have forgotten localdate. ;-)

Comment: @Kave: I was really hoping one of these solutions would work. I must say I based it on the documentation as I haven't encountered this particular problem in my projects yet. If you do find a solution, it would be good to post it here. Otherwise you could create a workaround that solves it. If there really is no easy way to do it then it's good to let the Django developers know.

Comment: Hi Simeon, sorry it took a bit longer to finish the demo. I have now created a tiny little app demonstrating the issue. https://dl.dropbox.com/u/44307777/Sandbox.zip  If you have a moment to have a look please. I have it very clearly right on main page how it doesn't work. :) If you can confirm you experience the same problem, then its a good candidate for me to raise a bug ticket. :D

Comment: Hi, after a long way and submitting this as a bug, I found the solution. You suggested `item.conversation_datetime|date|date:"DATE_FORMAT"` this indeed doesn't work. But you were very close. It should be `item.conversation_datetime|date:"DATE_FORMAT"` :) Please correct and I tick it as an answer.

Comment: @Kave: I'm glad that you found the solution. I've updated the answer above.